# Crawl and index a file with embedded contents in Search 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, search, enterprise-search

When I try to crawl a file (say a word doc) with embedded contents, the crawler shows a warning :

> This item was partially parsed. The item has been truncated in the
>   index because it exceeds the maximum size. ( Document
>   'file:///C:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20Office%20Servers/15.0/Data/Office%20Server/Applications/0d909b85-61d7-479f-9510-6fdef64350a3-crawl-0/gthrsvc//72/0x272_10000.docx'
>   was partially processed. The parser was not able to parse the entire
>   document.; )

And does not index the contents of the embedded file, where as the contents of the actual file are indexed. The embedded content here, is another simple word doc embedded as word object with icon and the entire file size is around 1MB.

Can search crawl a file with embedded contents?

Comment: The error indicates that the file (not the "attachment") is too big. How big is it?

Comment: Yes, I'm not really sure why. This is just a test file and the  file size is 400Kb, and the attached file size also 400Kb. The same error occurs with any file (when it has embedded content). However, when I crawl them individually there seems to be no issue.

Answer (score 0):

run these commands:

```
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication "Search Service Application"
Set-SPEnterpriseSearchFileFormatState -SearchApplication $ssa -Identity docx -Enable $true -UseIFilter $true
Set-SPEnterpriseSearchFileFormatState -SearchApplication $ssa -Identity pptx -Enable $true -UseIFilter $true
```

*WARNING: Please restart the SharePoint Search Host Controller service (or the content processing component) to update the system with your changes.*

```
net stop spsearchhostcontroller
net start spsearchhostcontroller
```

Comment: The commend is to enable 3rd party iFilter?

Comment: This is not 3rd party iFilter, if you want to use another iFilter you should get information about installation and commands within.